# How to open paper-dialog not on click

Tags: php, polymer

I have a function Clickandler(event) to show paper-dialog on click some button.

I want just to show paper-dialog on the page without pressing button, how can I do it?

Comment: Where is your code to show the dialogue on click?

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: sorry, posting a code: http://pastebin.com/HXLkRRFG
there's button and function which triggers on click

Comment: I just can't get what function is showing modal dialog, and how to call it from any place I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paper-dialog has a opened attribute. you can add that to your dialog and by default it will be opened

```
<paper-dialog id="someDialog" opened>
```

or in javascript

```
document.querySelector('#someDialog').open();
```

or

```
document.querySelector('#someDialog').opened = true;
```